# DNS RPZ zone queries are being "refused"

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I am testing out the BIND Response Policy Zone feature on our lab DNS server. We run a RHEL 6 server with BIND 9.8.2. I have followed the instructions [here](http://redpill-linpro.com/sysadvent/2015/12/08/dns-rpz.html) but I can't get it to work. Here is what I know:

1) The DNS server DOES respond to queries for hosts found in other zones

2) My RPZ zone loads successfully, as can be seen here:

```
Jan 28 12:00:13 labdns named[26564]: zone rpz/IN: loaded serial 2015012816
```

But here is what I see in /var/log/messages when I query for a domain found in the RPZ zone:

```
Jan 28 11:52:54 labdns named[26060]: client 192.168.254.202#38524: query (cache) 'x99moyu.net/A/IN' denied
```

I have seen this behavior before but only when you have recursion off and you query for a host that is not found in a zone file. Here is my RPZ zone db file:

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA   localhost. root.localhost. (

                            2015012816      ; serial
                                    3600    ; refresh
                                    1800    ; retry
                                    604800  ; expire
                                    86400   ; minimum
)

@                               IN      NS        lab.testdns.net.

; Response Policy for x99moyu.net
x99moyu.net                 IN      A       127.0.0.1
                            IN      AAAA    ::1
; Response Policy for ix99moyu.net
ix99moyu.net                IN      A       127.0.0.1
                            IN      AAAA    ::1
; Response Policy for duobao369.com
duobao369.com               IN      A       127.0.0.1
                            IN      AAAA    ::1
```

I have tried putting dots both in front and behind the domain names but that did not help and the instructions say not to use dots anyway.

Here is my /etc/named.conf file:

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND    named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver   only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration     files.
//

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 192.168.155.128; }; #Master DNS Servers IP
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named.stats";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.155.0/24; 192.168.254.0/23;    192.168.160.0/24; }; # IP range of hosts
    allow-transfer  { localhost; 192.168.254.202; }; # Slave DNS     server
    recursion no;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;
    zone-statistics yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    response-policy { zone "rpz"; };
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
    channel rpz-queries {
    file "/var/log/bind/rpz.log" versions 10 size 50m;
    severity info;
};
    category rpz {
    rpz-queries;
    };
};

zone"rpz" IN {
type master;
file "/var/named/db.rpz";
notify yes;
allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

I am not sure how to move forward or how to debug this further. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT - Here is the output from a dig command. This is where I see the "refused" message

```
dig @192.168.155.128 x99moyu.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P2-RedHat-9.10.3-7.P2.fc22 <<>> @192.168.155.128   x99moyu.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 51880
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;x99moyu.net.           IN  A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.155.128#53(192.168.155.128)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 28 12:30:08 CST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell the issue doesn't seem to actually involve RPZ, but rather just comes down to that you have a setup that relies on recursion (ie, it appears that you expect to process queries for names that are not in any of your own zones?) but you have recursion turned off in your configuration.

```
recursion no;
```

Now, technically, the lookup of the specific name in the query would have been overridden by means of your RPZ configuration but the query gets refused before that as recursion is off and the queried name part of one of your zones.